# Adjust the Skeleton bones position in Kinect for windows sdk 1.5

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I'm making a wpf application using Kinect for windows sdk 1.5 and I want to know how to adjust the bones of the skeleton depending on the person standing in front of the kinect, i mean if i stand first the skeleton appears ok, and if my brother whose neck and arms are taller than me the skeleton bones doesn't change.

So how to adjust this?

many thanks

Comment: Do you want to scale the skeleton based on the user his height so that everyone's skeleton is equal?

Comment: exactly, I mean when I run my application the skeleton is drawn over my body, and when my professor  the same skeleton is drawn although I'm thinner and taller, so how to adjust this?

Answer (score 0):

just run the Skeleton-Basics sample(Windows developer toolkit). And of course have a look at its code. It scales the skeleton.

Comment: There is no skeleton scaling in this project... It only matches the depth image which is drawn into window.